# COUNT for IN statement (count from scope, not from a table)

Tags: mysql

My question is pretty simple:

I want to select user_id, count(user_id) from a scope (not from a table). Is this even possible?

Example:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5);
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
id| count
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 2
5 | 1
```

My really code:

```
set_of_user_ids = (1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)
cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id IN %s', (set_of_user_ids,))
```

Comment: Why `FROM users` whereas you want to count values in the query text (or in CSV string transferred into the query as a parameter)?

Comment: Well, FROM "what" I must write?

Comment: In shown code you must use FIND_IN_SET() function instead of IN operator. `cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(user_id, %s)', (set_of_user_ids,))`.

Comment: Anyway, this does not help with COUNT()

Comment: this is homework and so there are a bunch of the same question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823790/count-for-in-statement-count-from-scope-not-from-a-table

Comment: I posted this question since there were no suitable answers :)

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()` function even for not tables with `AS` keyword.

`SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) FROM (SELECT user_id FROM scope) AS some_name GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(user_id);`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that should work :

```
select a.user_id, count(1) as count, count(u.user_id) as num_in_users_table
from 
(select 1 as user_id 
union all
select 2 
...
union all
select 10
)a
left join users u on u.user_id=a.user_id
group by a.user_id
```

Update - it should be  `union all` if you want duplicates to be counted properly.

Comment: It is not suitable for many user_ids, as every `select` is written by the hands

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VALUES` statement to store scope related values & then can `GROUP BY` and count values from it.

```
 select col1, count(*)
 from (values row(1),row(2),row(3),row(3),row(4),row(2)) as temp(col1)
 group by col1;
+------+----------+
| col1 | count(*) |
+------+----------+
|    1 |        1 |
|    2 |        2 |
|    3 |        2 |
|    4 |        1 |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: I don't think `FROM ( VALUES ... )` is valid MySQL syntax; please provide a reference.

Comment: @RickJames   VALUES is a DML statement introduced in MySQL 8.0.19 which returns a set of one or more rows as a table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

Comment: Thanks.  (It's still warm from the oven!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

To find the number of items in a string.  This will work for a given delimiter.  It does not de-dup.

```
mysql> SET @list := '1,22,333,4567,9,8';


mysql> SELECT LENGTH(@list) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@list, ',', '')) + 1;
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| LENGTH(@list) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@list, ',', '')) + 1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   6 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```